# PHP interprets -> as a close tag

Tags: php

When I type somewhere in my code

```
<?  
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../inc/config.inc.php');

if ($Admin->Connected && $Admin->HasRight('menu_Contact_Subscription', USER))
{
```

It shows me an raw output like this on the screen:

> Connected && $Admin->HasRight('menu_Contact_Subscription', USER))
>   {

Why does this happen?

Comment: Is it only one block of code this is happening to. Or does it echo the entire file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: It could be that something in `config.inc.php` is causing this problem. Does that open or close tags anywhere?

Comment: my suspicion is that config.inc.php has something strange in it, that let's php think that `->` is the end of something...a docblock maybe? but I am confused, too, I've never seen this behaviour. You could try to copy the content of the config.inc.php into the code file and see if your editor's syntax highliting gives any hints

Comment: @insertusernamehere In this case, I think there's something more going on than just a PHP file failing to execute. Otherwise, the entire `if` statement would be echoed.

Comment: @BenHillier [Why do you think so?](https://jsfiddle.net/avermno9/) ;)

Comment: @insertusernamehere I stand corrected. It's interpreting the tags as HTML of course! Then indeed: the PHP is simply failing to execute.

Comment: @insertusernamehere of course, you are right. do you want to expand your explanation into a beginner-friendly answer?

Comment: Php should give expected output. If not this may have a lot of causes. Check related functions if there's mistakes. Especially if you use header(); function it usually gives errors similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
<?
```

with the following:

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check php opening tag `<?php` 
I think so;